# How to use ggplot2's annotate with dates in x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem understanding the difference between `geom_segment` and `annotate(segment, ...)` when it comes to plots with dates on the `x` axis.

Let's start with some random data:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

# Prepare some random data
set.seed(1234)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(365*5), d = seq(ymd(20130101), ymd(20131231), by = 86400))
dt.m <- dt[, list(total = sum(x)), by = list(month = floor_date(d, "month"))]
# Create a basic scatterplot chart
p <- qplot(month, total, data = dt.m)
```

Both of the following work and add a segment to the plot `p` defined above:

```
# Both of these work as expected and produce the same result
p + geom_segment(x = as.numeric(ymd(20130401)), xend = as.numeric(ymd(20130701)), 
  y = -10, yend = 10)
p + geom_segment(aes(x = ymd(20130401), xend = ymd(20130701), 
  y = -10, yend = 10))
```

[image: ggplot2 chart with geom_segment]

However, neither of the following `annotate("segment", ...)` calls work - and they produce different error messages, which I cannot really parse.

```
> p + annotate("segment", x = as.numeric(ymd(20130401)), xend = as.numeric(ymd(20130701)), 
  y = -10, yend = 10)
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

> p + annotate("segment", x = ymd(20130401), xend = ymd(20130701), 
  y = -10, yend = 10)
Error in Ops.POSIXt((x - from[1]), diff(from)) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects 

> p + annotate("segment", aes(x = ymd(20130401), xend = ymd(20130701), 
  y = -10, yend = 10))
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""uneval"" to a data.frame
```

I modelled the `annotate("segment", ...)` calls after receipt 7.4 in R Graphics Cookbook, and it seems to work fine with simple graphs that have no dates in x-axis.

I would appreciate if someone can explain what's really going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in ggplot2 [(ggplot2 google groups discussion)](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ggplot2/8Cm3XyDODnI/_KwVPziqTmkJ). I have submitted a [new ticket](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/859).

Comment: seems this bug is back... any news in progress?

Comment: I just ran into this bug again as well. Should I submit a ticket?