# ggplot2 annotation with dates in x-axis

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw an area plot with a series of % value, one for each day during a set period. I would like to add a segment to the top of the plot to show more clearly the areas where the % is decreasing.

I tried to use this code (the example has just a few data points for simplicity):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
limit = c(0.85,0.87,0.88,0.90,0.72,0.74)
day <- as.Date(strptime((seq(20150201,20150206,1)),format = "%Y%m%d"))
dati = data.frame("Day" = day, "Limit" = limit)
g <- ggplot(data = dati, aes(Day, Limit))
g <- g + geom_area(fill = "dark red")
g <- g + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1))
g <- g + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
g <- g + annotate("segment", y= 1, yend = 1, x = dati[3, "Day"], xend = dati[4, "Day"])
print(g)
```

But I get this error: ***Error: / not defined for "Date" objects***

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I already checked [How to use ggplot2's annotate with dates in x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796386/how-to-use-ggplot2s-annotate-with-dates-in-x-axis), but it appears the bug is back. Plus I'd like to do this without using the lubridate package.

Comment: Can't comment on whether it's a bug reincarnation, but the following works:
`+ geom_segment(y= 1, yend = 1, x = as.numeric(dati[3, "Day"]), xend = as.numeric(dati[4, "Day"]))`

Comment: You are welcome. There's an issue on github, drop a note there if you desire. Link to it is in the q&a you linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping my earlier comment into an answer: use `geom_segment` instead.

```
+ geom_segment(y = 1, yend = 1, 
               x = as.numeric(dati[3, "Day"]), xend = as.numeric(dati[4, "Day"]))
```

[image]